# Size of a request header field exceeds server limit due to many If-None-Match values

Tags: server, apache2

Here's an interesting case of a client getting the a "400 Bad Request" error and seemingly unable to view a drupal home page hosted on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS using Apache/2.2.22:

> **Bad Request**
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.

Packet sniffing output:

```
...
T 2013/09/02 15:23:10.458167 ###.###.###.###:40027 -> ###.###.###.###:80 [A]
GET / HTTP/1.0.
If-None-Match: "1363160742-0", "1363165573-1", "1363175854-1", "1363175854-0", "1363179616-0", "1363181811-0", "1363239319-1", "1363255903-0", "1363259282-0", "1363263398-1", "1363274564-0", "1363329642-0", "1363332613-1", "1363333851-0", "1363599826-0", "1363678909-0", "1363684227-1", "1363699732-0", "1363755181-0", "1363765691-1", "1363767178-0", "1363780208-0", "1363787589-0", "1363795259-1", "1363852409-1", "1363863225-1", "1363928115-0", "1363951793-0", "1363951793-1", "1364133610-1", "1364187608-1", "1364187608-0", "1364203083-0", "1364208174-0", "1364214930-0", "1364219815-0", "1364274441-1", "1364280930-0", "1364280930-1", "1364286055-1", "1364298840-0", "1364298840-1", "1364360674-0", "1364364356-1", "1364381508-0", "1364385520-1", "1364460734-0", "1364882595-1", "1364903271-0", "1364967946-0", "1364967946-1", "1364981713-0", "1364985142-1", "1364992835-1", "1365061578-0", "1365065290-1", "1365076128-0", "1365141088-1", "1365167701-0", "1365171024-0", "1365402404-1", "1365402404-0", "1365411731-1", "1365416882-0", "1365476715-0", "1365487578-0", "1365488880-1", "1365503922-1", "1365514224-1", "1365579101-0", "1365580320-0", "1365582817-0", "1365584926-0", "1365589524-0", "1365608307-0", "1365649987-0", "1365682295-0", "1365685083-0", "1365770532-1", "1365770532-0", "1365844566-0", "1365996619-1", "1366093719-1", "1366093719-0", "1366115408-0", "1366180275-1", "1366186431-0", "1366196476-0", "13662669
...
```

At this stage I am not 100% sure whether it is just limited to a specific client but the error was reported by a user with the following user agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/534.57.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.7
```

Now the question remains what to do, is it a server issue or just a misbehaving client?

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu question. Take a look at the Apache logs and use that to procure help among the specialised community.

Comment: My thoughts were that it may be a Ubuntu defaults issue.

Comment: We are talking about a webserver running on Ubuntu - so it is not off-topic per-se. As @LuísdeSousa suggested, look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, to find what limit was violated.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa We support all parts of Ubuntu Server here. Why wouldn't this be an Ubuntu question?

Comment: @guntbert the interesting part is that neither the request not the actual error is ever logged in the apache logs. It is logged in the squid reverse proxy and I'm guessing that the proxy is actually the cause

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've found the problem. Some user agents and some requests just get too big for web server defaults. It seems like a silly problem to run into but it keeps happening to me in `nginx`. Usually when there are silly cookie names and uploads going on... Anyway...

The solution is to just bump the request limit. You can do this globally or just for your site with [the `LimitRequestFieldSize` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize):

```
LimitRequestFieldSize 32768
```

That's a 32KB (up from the default of 8KB) limit.

Comment: That is what I was thinking but I was not sure about the recommended size. Thanks!

Comment: Increasing `LimitRequestFieldSize` to `32768` didn't help.

Comment: @inetpro Did you restart Apache? And is it at a high enough context? This won't work in an .htaccess file.

Comment: I added it in the VirtualHost context of the relevant site and have searched for a similar setting in all configs to make sure that it isn't overridden by another instance. Oh and yes I did restart apache. What really bugs me is the many If-None-Match values, is that normal?

Comment: I changed the subject to be more relevant.

Comment: Did you put the entry in the first name based virtual host defined, or in another one? The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfields) says: "When name-based virtual hosting is used, the value for this directive is taken from the default (first-listed) virtual host for the NameVirtualHost the connection was mapped to.". It looks like you're better off doing this in the global config. The problem with doing it in a virtual host is that it is the request header itself contains name of the required virtual host.

Comment: @RobieBasak I just moved the entry to the global config, restarted and just received feedback and confirmation that the site can now be opened with Safari.

Comment: ⓵`LimitRequestFieldSize 65536` ⓶`LimitRequestLine 65536` ⓷`LimitXMLRequestBody 0` ⓸??? ⓹ℙℛṎℱỈᎢ☕